# split string value in a python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

I have a dict with a key value pair where some have one position ex. 'A' and some have multiple positions ex. 'A,B' . Is there a way for me to split the ones with multiple positions so I can use both. I'm currently getting a key error because python wants to look up 'A,B' when I want it to look up 'A','B'. Please see below.

```
dict = {1 : 'A' , 2: 'A,B' , 3:'C,D'}
```

if I wanted to print to values for 2 I would want the out put to be:

```
A
B
```

or some form where they are separate so I will stop getting the key error.

Here is the actual bit of code with the KeyError for my project that is causing me trouble.

```
         for pos in playerPos[player]:
             team_pos[playerPos[player]] += 1
             

KeyError: '1B,OF'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `split` value:

```py
for pos in playerPos[player].split(','):
    team_pos[pos] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to separate the value in dict

`playerPos[player].split(',')`